# Jquery SimpleTabs issue with Chrome v62.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

For some reason the JQuery UI SimpleTabs have just stopped working in my site and I can only put it down to the Google Chrome v62.0.3202.62 update, as it worked fine in previous versions up to v61.0.3163.100.

Basically the tab text doesn't show up, but more importantly the onclick events on the tabs don't fire either.

Problem is I get no warning or error messages in the Google console - just the usual woff errors because I'm using web fonts.

Has anybody had similar problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found that it was an overflow:hidden issue in the css even though this has worked fine up to this point in Chrome and still works in the other browsers.  Commented this out and everything back to normal.